# Conv2D and Conv3D: increase the accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, caffe, pytorch

I have 10000 RGB images with 18 * 18 pixels (yes, images are small sized) for each of 5 classes. I wanted to make deep learning model for classification of images into 5 labels. I tried both Conv2D and Conv3D, with kernels (3,3) and (3,3,3) respectively. I tried adding multiple layers (up to 8) with different filters (16, 32, 64, 128, 256). I tried different activators (relu, sigmoid) and optimizers (adam, sgd). I also tried # epochs upto 500. However, I could not get more than 0.5 overall accuracy by any means. Please help me guys how can I increase the accuracy.

Comment: The image size is pretty small so I would recommend around 2 Conv2D layers. Try lower learning rate and adam optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look for good example like "mnist cnn" and apply that model to your dataset.

I think you need other something, not only network architecture.

It could be below.

- Data Augmentation : rotation, scaling, shift, etc.
- Initialization : parameter initialization(weight, bias)
- Batch norm
- Drop out
- Decayed learning rate by epoch

Comment: I also used VGG16 network architecture (without model weights because it was trained for imagenet dataset and I'm working for my own images), but no improvement.

Comment: I think it is not good way to use VGG16 network, because VGG16 is too big architecture to apply your image(18x18 input). mnist image is 28x28 size bigger than yours and it is just enough to use several conv layer with several technique I mentioned above.

Comment: @user10772275 No. VGG16 won't even accept 18*18 input.

Answer (score 0):

first of all try to encrease data samples per class (try ti collect real new data after that augment them all)
eventhough your data is not similar to imagenet classes use on of the state-of-art pre-trained model (such as mobile net v2 or Xceptoin) as initial weights and fine tune it by you data
if your samples are similar to imagenet you can freeze the first layers and only train the dense layers in the end of model.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents:

- In terms of model architecture start simple and increase capacity (layers filters) along the way if necessary.
- Speaking from my experience, the learning rate of your optimizer has the most impact. So at first keeping all other parameters fixed and just finding a good learning rate is a good start.
- Use Adam, it is less sensitive to bad learning rates.
- In the beginning there is actually no need to use fancy augmentation on your data, dropout or weight-regularization. These methods are used to help your model to prevent overfitting. Since you're stuck at 0.5 accuracy, your not really overfitting.
- Batch-Normalization can work wonders for CNNs.
- If your data is imbalanced, try using a weighted loss.

Some of the points mentioned above (and many more) are taken from Andrej Karpathy's Blog post called [A recipe for training neural networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/).